# Unable to logout successfully using NSUserDefault

Tags: objective-c, xib

when i click on logout button view come on login page and again my home page open.. this is my issue..

here is my code-
this code for check the value in `NSUserDefault`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    // cheq the value in NSUserdeafault

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"login"] boolValue]) {

        HomePage *mainView = [[HomePage alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomePage" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
    }
}
```

and this one is for logout button

```
- (IBAction)logout_btn:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:@"0" forKey:@"logout"];

[defaults synchronize];
         LoginPage *log = [[LoginPage alloc] init];
        MyNavigationController *navController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:log];
        navController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;

        [menuController setRootController:navController animated:NO];


}
```

please give me solution

Comment: Seems you did not  pasted the logout button code but the view will appear code twice. Please post you logout button code.

Comment: @rckoenes sir, here is my logout button code

Comment: Why would you hold "login" status in `NSUserDefaults`?  That is ridiculous.

Comment: at one point you are setting the value of logout key and at the other you are checking the value of login key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Bool data type for "login" key.

when you login  use this :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"login"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

when logout button clicked set this :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"login"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: - (IBAction)logout_btn:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setValue:@"0" forKey:@"logout"];
   
    [defaults synchronize];
             LoginPage *log = [[LoginPage alloc] init];
            MyNavigationController *navController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:log];
            navController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;
            
            [menuController setRootController:navController animated:NO];
        
    
}
sir this is my logout button code

Comment: So what does holding `YES`/`NO` in `NSUserDefaults` actually mean?  Surely being logged-in means you have an active network connection and have been authenticated?  So how do you get those things?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a string to you UserDefault which will make your check true.

`NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:@"0" forKey:@"logout"];`

it should be something like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@NO forKey:@"logout"];
```

or

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"logout:]; // explicitly indicating that you are setting a BOOL
```

then in your check you can use

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logout"]; // you won't need to specify boolValue anymore unless you use the first option (setValue:@NO)
```